# Determine distance from the top of a 'div' to top of the window with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I determine the distance between the very top of a div to the top of the current screen?

I just want the pixel distance to the top of the current screen, not the top of the document.  I've tried a few things like `.offset()` and `.offsetHeight`, but I just can't wrap my brain around it.

Comment: you might want to [check this out](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html)

Comment: `el.getBoundingClientRect().top+window.scrollY`

Comment: @caub Eh, it's just `el.getBoundingClientRect().top`. Adding the scroll position adds up to the distance to the top of the document. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: yea right, just wanted to unjquerify

Answer (score 265, accepted):

You can use `.offset()` to get the offset compared to the `document` element and then use the `scrollTop` property of the `window` element to find how far down the page the user has scrolled:

```
var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
    elementOffset = $('#my-element').offset().top,
    distance      = (elementOffset - scrollTop);
```

The `distance` variable now holds the distance from the top of the `#my-element` element and the top-fold.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rxs2m/

Note that negative values mean that the element is above the top-fold.

Comment: How can I check if the distance is a specific number? I want to make an element sticky if it is 120px away from the top

Comment: @ThessaVerbruggen You can check the `distance` variable to see if it's value is `120` but I would recommend checking for a range instead of an exact number. If for instance you scroll with a mouse-wheel, you might very well skip over 120. So if you are trying to apply some CSS or something when the element is within 120px of the top-fold, then maybe use `if (distance < 120) { /* do something */}`. Here is an updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/na5qL91o/

Comment: One problem if I do this: the sticky part is flashing when I scroll. I guess because it recalculates when I scroll. Any idea how to fix this?
My code:
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
       var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
           elementOffset = $('#secondary').offset().top,
           distance      = (elementOffset - scrollTop);

       if (distance < 120) {
        $('#secondary').addClass('sticky');
       } else {
        $('#secondary').removeClass('sticky');
       }
   });

Answer (score 94):

Vanilla:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(ev) {

   var someDiv = document.getElementById('someDiv');
   var distanceToTop = someDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top;

   console.log(distanceToTop);
});
```

Open your browser console and scroll your page to see the distance.

Comment: This only works if the user hasn't scrolled the page.  Otherwise `distanceToTop` returned is relative (can even be negative if the user has scrolled past).

To take this into account, use `window.pageYOffset + someDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top`

Comment: @ty The OP is looking for the distance to the top of the screen, not to the top of the document - a negative value  would be valid in this case

Comment: This is also what I needed. I'm using Vue-toasted library and it only allows showing the toasts at absolute positions on the screen. I wanted the toast to show up close to the button I was clicking in a table and ultimately needed to use getBoundingClientRect().top in a scroll event.  I also did the same in a resize event. May want to consider adding that when calculating distance to top of screen like this - never know what the client will end up doing.

Comment: @ty. Meanwhile `window.pageYOffset` is deprecated. Better use `window.scrollY`.

Comment: @ty. So helpful!

Answer (score 38):

This can be achieved **purely with JavaScript**.

**I see the answer I wanted to write has been answered by [lynx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3004669/lynx) in comments to the question.**

But I'm going to write answer anyway because just like me, people sometimes forget to read the comments.

So, if you just want to get an element's distance (in Pixels) from the top of your screen window, here is what you need to do:

```
// Fetch the element
var el = document.getElementById("someElement");
```

use [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

```
// Use the 'top' property of 'getBoundingClientRect()' to get the distance from top
var distanceFromTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

Thats it!

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: getBoundingClient() doesn't work, instead .getBoundingClientRect()

Comment: Just awesome work @MohammedFurqanRahamathM. Thank you so much for your answer :) It works like a charm !! :)

Comment: @MerianosNikos Thank you. I'm glad it was of help :)

Comment: but this would only work if you're haven't reloaded in the middle of the page right?

Comment: @SagiveSEO I didn't understand. Could you please elaborate your question?

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect()` gets the position from the top of the viewport. That is, if you have a div 500px from the top of the start of the page, and scroll 500px `el.getBoundingClientRect().top` returns `0`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. That was the actual question i.e., the person who posted this question needed the distance in pixels to the top of the 'div' in "current" screen.

Answer (score 8):

I used this:

```
                              myElement = document.getElemenById("xyz");
Get_Offset_From_Start       ( myElement );  // returns positions from website's start position
Get_Offset_From_CurrentView ( myElement );  // returns positions from current scrolled view's TOP and LEFT
```

code:

```
function Get_Offset_From_Start (object, offset) { 
    offset = offset || {x : 0, y : 0};
    offset.x += object.offsetLeft;       offset.y += object.offsetTop;
    if(object.offsetParent) {
        offset = Get_Offset_From_Start (object.offsetParent, offset);
    }
    return offset;
}

function Get_Offset_From_CurrentView (myElement) {
    if (!myElement) return;
    var offset = Get_Offset_From_Start (myElement);
    var scrolled = GetScrolled (myElement.parentNode);
    var posX = offset.x - scrolled.x;   var posY = offset.y - scrolled.y;
    return {lefttt: posX , toppp: posY };
}
//helper
function GetScrolled (object, scrolled) {
    scrolled = scrolled || {x : 0, y : 0};
    scrolled.x += object.scrollLeft;    scrolled.y += object.scrollTop;
    if (object.tagName.toLowerCase () != "html" && object.parentNode) { scrolled=GetScrolled (object.parentNode, scrolled); }
    return scrolled;
}

    /*
    // live monitoring
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (evt) {
        var Positionsss =  Get_Offset_From_CurrentView(myElement);  
        console.log(Positionsss);
    });
    */
```

Comment: +1 for showing that element.offsetTop exists. element.getBoundingClientRect().top is giving me strange behaviour. I was looking to get the distance from the top of the webpage until the top of the element.

Answer (score 0):

I used this function to detect if the element is visible in the view port.

Code:

```
const vh = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0);

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    elementOffset = $('.for-scroll').offset().top,
    distance      = (elementOffset - scrollTop);
    if(distance < vh) {
        console.log('in view');
    }
    else {
        console.log('not in view');
    }
});
```

Comment: How does that answer the question?