# How to get the distance from the top for an element?

Tags: javascript

I want to know how to use JavaScript to get the distance of an element from **the top of the page not the parent element**.
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/yZGSt/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine distance from the top of a div to top of window with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880472/determine-distance-from-the-top-of-a-div-to-top-of-window-with-javascript)

Answer (score 162):

```
var elDistanceToTop = window.pageYOffset + el.getBoundingClientRect().top
```

In my experience `document.body.scrollTop` doesn't always return the current scroll position (for example if the scrolling actually happens on a different element).

Comment: Unlike the top answer, this DOES work on iOS Safari. Don't use 2 hours on debugging like I did :)

Comment: @Sami Al-Subhi this should be the selected answer.

Comment: `pageYOffset` is deprecated now.

Comment: `pageYOffset` is an alias for `scrollY`

Answer (score 106):

offsetTop only looks at the element's parent. Just loop through parent nodes until you run out of parents and add up their offsets.

```
function getPosition(element) {
    var xPosition = 0;
    var yPosition = 0;

    while(element) {
        xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
        yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }

    return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}
```

UPDATE: This answer has some problems, values will have tiny differences compare to what it should be and will not work correctly in some cases.

Check [**@eeglbalazs**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50310297/7942242), which is accurate.

Comment: element in this case would be something like:
`var element = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper')[0];`

Comment: insanely useful!

Comment: @Colton45 actually you should use `document.querySelector('.wrapper')`

Comment: Just to further add to this, this implementation does not function the same in Safari as Chrome - therefore I would argue it should not be accepted. Here is a demo (scroll on both browsers): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaKEPK.

This implementation https://stackoverflow.com/a/53351648/775007 works.

Comment: @Dean You sure about that? It's working for me in every brower and OS I have available. 

I think you might have confused yourself by using vh units in your css lol.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zXqqbP

Comment: @ShawnWhinnery Yes i'm sure. I just tried your codepen and the behaviour is the same. The value changes as you scroll in one browser and doesn't in the other :)

Answer (score 16):

Here is some interesting code for you :)

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  //get the element
  var elem = document.getElementById('test');
  //get the distance scrolled on body (by default can be changed)
  var distanceScrolled = document.body.scrollTop;
  //create viewport offset object
  var elemRect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  //get the offset from the element to the viewport
  var elemViewportOffset = elemRect.top;
  //add them together
  var totalOffset = distanceScrolled + elemViewportOffset;
  //log it, (look at the top of this example snippet)
  document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = totalOffset;
});
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 100vh;
}
#log {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: table;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
html,
body {
  height: 2000px;
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 15):

Use [`offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop)

```
document.getElementById("foo").offsetTop
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yZGSt/2/)

Comment: This returns distance from offsetParent. Is their a way to get it from the top of the page?

Comment: In my testing that has given me the correct result every time. Do you have a case where it does not?

Comment: @sachleen, http://jsfiddle.net/HxDEt/1/ shows that your answer is incorrect if any container elements have relative, absolute, or fixed position (and have an offsetTop themselves).

Comment: `el.getBoundingClientRect().top`

Answer (score 11):

This oneliner seems to work nice

```
document.getElementById("el").getBoundingClientRect().top +  window.scrollY
```

[your fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/7nzguLfp/)

Comment: This should be top, the top answer is using a depreciated method +1

Answer (score 9):

offsetTop doesn’t get the distance to the top of the page, but rather to the top of the closest parent element that has a specified position.

You can use a simple technique that adds up the offsetTop of all the parent element of the element you are interested in to get the distance.

```
// Our element
var elem = document.querySelector('#some-element');

// Set our distance placeholder
var distance = 0;

// Loop up the dom
do {
    // Increase our distance counter
    distance += elem.offsetTop;

    // Set the element to it's parent
    elem = elem.offsetParent;

} while (elem);
distance = distance < 0 ? 0 : distance;
```

Original code from https://gomakethings.com/how-to-get-an-elements-distance-from-the-top-of-the-page-with-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: It's surreal to Google how to do something and discover a StackOverflow answer that links back an article YOU wrote. LOL thanks for this!

Answer (score 6):

```
var distanceTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

For details vist a link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: This will not give actual height from top. It returns the height from top at current scrolled state of the window.

Answer (score 3):

**For anchor links (`href="/#about"`) to anchor `<div id="about">` read part 3.

## 1 (distance_from_top)

**Less than 30 seconds solution (Two lines of code "hello world"):**

### get your element:

```
var element = document.getElementById("hello");
```

### Get getBoundingClientRect ();

> The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns the size of an
> element and its position relative to the viewport. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

```
var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
```

**Return object:**

[image]

### Dot notation `top`

```
var distance_from_top = rect.top; /* 1007.9971313476562 */
```

Thats it.

## 2 (window.scrollTo)

### StackOverflow nightmare 2 - set scroll position to this value

Again "hello world" (8,000 answers out there - 7,999 not working or to complex).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

```
  window.scrollTo({
    top: element.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
```

Add offset value to `top` if you want (For sticky navbars).

### "Hello World" code snippet (Get distance from top viewport + click to `scrollTo`)

```js
var element = document.getElementById("hello");
var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
var distance_from_top = rect.top; /* 50px */
console.log(distance_from_top);

function scrollTovView(){
  window.scrollTo({
    top: distance_from_top,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

```css
div{
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="scrollTovView()">scrollTo to red DIV</button>
<div style="height: 50px;">50px height</div>
<div id="hello" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background: red;"></div>
```

## 3 (scrollTo & anchors)

### scrollTo "conflict" with main anchor navbars

This trick is very **buggy** if, for example, you use this URL:

```
www.mysite/about#hello
```

to

```
<div id="hello">hello</div>
```

`top` is 0 or buggy (The HTML moves to `hello` section).

```
  window.scrollTo({
    top: element.getBoundingClientRect().top, 
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
```

For this code to work you should add:

```
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();
```

Basic example her:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp

Answer (score 2):

Although it is quite an old discussion, but this works pretty well on `chrome / firefox / safari` browsers:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
   var someDiv = document.getElementById('someDiv');
   var distanceToTop = someDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top;
});
```

Check it out on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yz7gzry7/)

Answer (score 2):

scroll to element's top position;

```
var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
var offsetTop = window.pageYOffset + rect.top - rect.height;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("id").offsetTop
```

Answer (score 1):

(SOURCE : [Determine distance from the top of a div to top of window with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880472/determine-distance-from-the-top-of-a-div-to-top-of-window-with-javascript/32737911#32737911) )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myyElement = document.getElementById("myyy_bar");  //your element
var EnableConsoleLOGS = true;                          //to check the results in Browser's Inspector(Console), whenever you are scrolling



// ==============================================
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (evt) {
    var Positionsss =  GetTopLeft ();  
    if (EnableConsoleLOGS) { console.log(Positionsss); }
});
function GetOffset (object, offset) {
    if (!object) return;
    offset.x += object.offsetLeft;       offset.y += object.offsetTop;
    GetOffset (object.offsetParent, offset);
}
function GetScrolled (object, scrolled) {
    if (!object) return;
    scrolled.x += object.scrollLeft;    scrolled.y += object.scrollTop;
    if (object.tagName.toLowerCase () != "html") {          GetScrolled (object.parentNode, scrolled);        }
}

function GetTopLeft () {
    var offset = {x : 0, y : 0};        GetOffset (myyElement, offset);
    var scrolled = {x : 0, y : 0};      GetScrolled (myyElement.parentNode, scrolled);
    var posX = offset.x - scrolled.x;   var posY = offset.y - scrolled.y;
    return {lefttt: posX , toppp: posY };
}
// ==============================================
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This function returns distance from top of the page, even if your window is scrolled. It can be used in event listeners.

```js
const getElementYOffset = (element) => {
  const scrollOnWindow =
    window.pageYOffset !== undefined
      ? window.pageYOffset
      : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body)
          .scrollTop;
  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  let distanceFromTopOfPage = rect.top;
  if (scrollOnWindow !== 0) {
    distanceFromTopOfPage = rect.top + scrollOnWindow;
  }

  return distanceFromTopOfPage;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need this line

```
document.getElementById("el").getBoundingClientRect().top
```

in which "el" is the element.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Since `window.pageYOffset` is a legacy alias of `window.scrollY`, eeglbalazs answer can be improved to:

```js
const elDistanceToTop = window.scrollY + el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

Answer (score -8):

Using jQuery's [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method:

```
$(element).offset().top
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yZGSt/3/

Comment: I'm not using jQuery. Thanks anyway :)