# HoWhy jquery "waypoints" doesn't work locally?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I've tried to use the [waypoint](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) library with jquery. I expected to see an alert when the user reaches the purple div. Quite oddly, it only works on the snippets in StackOverflow, but not locally.
Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("document is ready!");
    $('#purple').waypoint(function() {
        alert('reached purple');
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- JQuery CDN !-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- WayPoints CDN !-->
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color:blue;height:300px;width:auto" id="blue"></div>
    <div style="background-color:red;height:300px;width:auto" id="red"></div>
    <div style="background-color:green;height:300px;width:auto" id="green"></div>
    <div style="background-color:yellow;height:300px;width:auto" id="yellow"></div>
    <div style="background-color:purple;height:300px;width:auto" id="purple"></div>
    <div style="background-color:pink;height:300px;width:auto" id="pink"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have same js file included in your project on local ? jQuery v3.5.1 and waypoints v4.0.1 ?

Comment: I included them with the CDN and wrote the js code inside a script tag. It recognizes the libraries, but yet nothing happens.

Comment: Try to save CDN files to local and try it again