# how to find distance between window top position and my iframe start position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to find distance between window top position and my iframe start position.

I tried with this approach [Determine distance from the top of a div to top of window with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880472/determine-distance-from-the-top-of-a-div-to-top-of-window-with-javascript)
but it is not working for me.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: the div is inside the iframe or wraps the iframe?

Comment: sorry, i want the distance between iframe and window top. not the div. I will edit the question

Comment: what exactly does not work from that answer? do you get any errors?

Comment: $('#myframeId').offset().top is getting 'undefined' javascript error

Comment: Is your `script` at the end of the file? or are you adding an `onload` event? From what I can tell it's either that the `script` runs before the `iframe` loads or the `ID` is wrong.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I am pretty sure that script runs after iframe gets loadded and ID is also correct

Comment: Can you post your code? it's hard to say without seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried using this approach:

```
    var topDistance = $('iframe')[0].offsetTop;
```

With varying success. Which, with your tag name would be:

```
    var topDistance = $('#myframeId').offsetTop;
```