# Get item offset from the top of page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the top offset of a div, and I have the following code that gets run when the page gets scrolled:

```
var $elem = document.querySelector(selector);
var elemTop = $elem.offsetTop;
console.log(elemTop);
```

But when I scroll it always prints `0` to the console, even though the element is below the fold.

Comment: Does the element have an offsetParent? Docs say: `The HTMLElement.offsetTop read-only property returns the distance of the current element relative to the top of the offsetParent node.`

Comment: It looks like it, `$elem.offsetParent`, when I scroll I get an html element in the console.

Comment: Okay, so how to I get the offset to the root of the document?

Comment: You mean like [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880472/determine-distance-from-the-top-of-a-div-to-top-of-window-with-javascript)

Comment: Yes, but without jQuery

Comment: Read past the first answer.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
var elmTop = $elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;
```

[element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) gives the position within the viewport, and window.scrollY gives the distance from the top of the viewport to the top of the document.

Comment: An alternative would be to walk up the DOM using element.offsetParent, adding each node's offsetTop together to get the measurement.  This is more complicated, but probably more efficient than calculating the values of getBoundingClientRect, which is something to be mindful of when executing anything onScroll.

Answer (score 2):

Solution how to check if the scroll has reached a certain element:

```
    const getOffsetTop = function(element) {
        if (!element) return 0;
        return getOffsetTop(element.offsetParent) + element.offsetTop;
    };

    const $el = document.querySelector(".button");

    window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        console.log(window.scrollY + window.innerHeight > getOffsetTop($el));
    });
```