# Javascript to calculate pixel distance between top of div and top of document

Tags: javascript, html, css

As the title says, is there any function or simple method to calculate pixel distance between the top of a div and the top of the HTML document? All the questions I've seen on stackoverflow do it for top of div and top of viewport which is different than what I need. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't showed what you have tried so far which I always recommend. So you know the distance from the top of the viewport. What should you do next? Your search should have found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422189/get-item-offset-from-the-top-of-page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get item offset from the top of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422189/get-item-offset-from-the-top-of-page)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function you could use, but I'm not sure it works on all contexts :

```
function topRelativeToDocumentElement(element) {
    var curCss, t=0;
    while (element!==null && element!==document.documentElement) {
        if ((defaultView=element.ownerDocument.defaultView) && (computedStyle=defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null))) {
            curCss=computedStyle.getPropertyValue("position");
        } else {
            curCss=null;
        }
        if (curCss!=="static" && curCss!=="fixed") {
            t+=element.offsetTop;
        } else if (curCss==="fixed") {
            t+=element.offsetTop;
            break;
        }
        if (typeof(element.parentNode)!=="undefined") {
            element=element.parentNode;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

[Edit]
I would advise to use this instead :

```
var top=elem.getBoundingClientRect().top - document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().top
```

The first function takes not in consideration css transforms, the second one does.

Comment: This is overkill and hard to read compared to something like `elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY`

Comment: Yes totally agree ! I should have answered this kind of advice. I took too literally the question.

Comment: but then if you set for example margins or top to the document element which is not common I agree, you can get wrong values with elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY then you'll have to do elem.getBoundingClientRect().top - document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().top