# How add / remove class based on div position / scrolltop.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've done a lot of research to try find a solution for this problem. I have a project where I am using parallax (magicScroll). I have a hamburger icon (where show/hide the menu), however this icon is black and I need change the color based on image background. So if I have a dark image as background the hamburger icon should be white and if I have a white background the icon should be black.

I've tried a lot of ways to do that, however I am using parallax. So I am having problems to write the function and I need help. My menu icon (.hamburger) is fixed at the header (position:fixed) and I have the sections below. The problem is: How identify the section in viewport (visible) and how add/remove the classe in my menu icon (.hamburger).

I was trying something like that:

```
 var setMenu = function() {
  if($('#section-3').inViewport()) {
    $('.hamburger').addClass('navwhite')
  } else {
    $('.hamburger').removeClass('navwhite')
  };
};
```

I was trying something like that to test, but without luck. :( Once my #section-3 hits the top of viewport, because the parallax, my ID never leaves this position, so I need help to learn how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `inViewport()` function is wrong for your case, it needs adjustments. Check some jQuery libraries as [this one](https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport).

Answer (score 0):

will check if page has been scrolled up to or greater then section "section-3" then "navwhite" class will be added otherwise it will be removed.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#section-3').offset().top) {
        $('.hamburger').addClass('navwhite')
    }
    if($(this).scrollTop() < $('#section-3').offset().top) {
        $('.hamburger').removeClass('navwhite')
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey Rahul, this works, however the 'else' is not working, because the parallax (I think)

Comment: Check my updated answer. I have removed else and used two if condition instead.

Comment: I just saw right now and after add your code, the same thing happened, else is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

The following code proves if an element has completely entered the viewport and sets or removes a class:

```
var section = $('.section');
var sectionTop = section.offset().top + section.height();

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    if (windowTop > sectionTop) {
          $('.hamburger').addClass('navwhite')
    }
    else {
        $('.hamburger').removeClass('navwhite')
    }
});
```

Comment: This works in parts. Once the class is added, 'else' is not working because the parallax.

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem addresses background and foreground colors as far as I understood, you could also have a look at the following library: [BackgroundCheck](http://www.kennethcachia.com/background-check/)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this answer: [Determine distance from the top of a div to top of window with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9880571/6774296).

Using Jaspers code, you are able to calculate the distance from a element to to top edge of the viewport.

Then you could compare the size of your background and it's current position on the screen:

```
// distance defined like in Jaspers answer linked above
if(distance <= 0 && distance >= (0-$('#section-3').outerHeight())){
$('.hamburger').addClass('navwhite');
}else{
$('.hamburger').removeClass('navwhite');
}
```

I have forked Jaspers JSFiddle to add a class `red` to the body element, as soon as the yellow square touches to upper document bound and removes the class, as soon as the yellow square stops touching the edge: http://jsfiddle.net/4psxe6uL/

Comment: Hello Rico, this is nice, but you need keep in mind I am using parallax.

Comment: @George What parallax script do you use? I tried my solution with http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/ and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I am using MagicScroll

Comment: @George Working for me too. Please note, that i changed `.height()` to `.outerHeight()` to include padding. (I edited that in my code above as well).

Comment: I've tried again and no success :( the function works fine but the 'else' is not working.

Comment: @George Weird. Do you only use jQuery and ScrollMagic? What Browser do you use?

Answer (score 0):

This is in pure js. It triggers on scroll and changes the class as necessary. 
Assumes body is your container element.

```
document.body.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
 if (document.body.scrollTop<document.querySelector('#section-3').style.height) {
   document.querySelector('.hamburger').setAttribute('class','navwhite');
 } else if (document.body.scrollTop>=document.querySelector('#section-3').style.height) {
  document.querySelector('.hamburger').removeAttribute('class');
 }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

its simple

```
jQuery( "classname/id of the div" ).eq(position of the div).addClass(new class name);
```

Comment: The question is about the div's position (=location) on the screen, not its index relative to the parent.