# javascript detect reach bottom mobile

Tags: javascript

```js
window.addEventListener('touchmove', handleScrollMobile)
        return () => window.removeEventListener('touchmove', handleScrollMobile)
        
        
function handleScrollMobile() {
        if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !== document.documentElement.offsetHeight || isFetching) return
        setIsFetching(true)
    }
```

this code works fine on desktop chrome mobile view but its not working on my android phone. the code sets 'setIsFetching' to true every time the user reaches the bottom of the page.

Comment: Whats up with the "return" after calling "addEventListener"?

Comment: did you review this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880472/determine-distance-from-the-top-of-a-div-to-top-of-window-with-javascript/9880571